# sqflite insert return zero

Tags: flutter, sqflite

In other places, database operations work perfectly but in one specific table insert operation returns 0 and no row is being inserted and no error produces.

I'm using version `sqflite: ^2.0.2+1`.
`sale.serial = await db.insert(tableSale, sale.toMap());`

Table creation code is:

```
db.execute('''
          create table $tableSale ( 
            $columnSerial integer primary key autoincrement, 
            $columnFbId integer not null,
            $columnBillID integer not null,
            $columnAmount real not null,
            $columnBalance real DEFAULT 0,
            $columnDiscount real DEFAULT 0,
            $columnFreight real DEFAULT 0,
            $columnAddedBy text not null,
            $columnDate text not null,
            $columnDateApproved integer,
            $columnFromPhone text not null,
            $columnToPhone text not null,
            $columnNote text,
            $columnDetail text,
            $columnItems text,
            UNIQUE($columnBillID) ON CONFLICT IGNORE)
          ''');
```

Comment: show us table creation code for `tableSale`

Comment: No flutter error? Have you tried to debug step-by-step the `.toMap` method? In the past, I had some errors in there that weren't easy to pinpoint without checking line by line during execution what happened. They were related to unexpected `null` values or wrong type conversion, like trying to get a `bool` from a `String` and such

Comment: @nitishk72 creation code added in the question.

Comment: @il_boga I have checked this but no luck, no flutter or database error.

Comment: 0 could be returned for some specific conflict algorithms if not inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
There is `UNIQUE($columnFbId) ON CONFLICT IGNORE)` in the table creation code and on conflict, the insert operation is being simply ignored with no Flutter or database error.

I found this by adding ConflictAlgorithm. The code is:
`sale.serial = await db.insert(tableSale, sale.toMap(), conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.fail)`

Thanks @nitishk72 for the hint.